# How to use a non-char list inside of an sql-LIKE wildcard?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, wildcard, sql-like

I'm trying to take the following code and make it DRY without VBA.
code (ms access 2007 sql):

```
SELECT *
FROM Student_Enrollment
WHERE ID LIKE '*2*'
OR ID LIKE '*5*'
OR ID LIKE '*8*'
OR ID LIKE '*17*'
OR ID LIKE '*14*'
OR ID LIKE '*11*'
OR ID LIKE '*21*'
```

It seems reasonable to me that something like the following should be possible:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student_Enrollment
WHERE ID LIKE '*[2,5,8,17,14,11,21]*'
```

but it doesn't work. It treats each list element as a list on its own, for example, it returns entries whose id contains 1 despite 1 not being in the list above, but 11 is in there and it thinks that 11 is just 1,1... how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do exactly what you want.  But you can simplify your logic to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student_Enrollment
WHERE ID LIKE "*[258]*" OR
      ID LIKE "*1[174]*" OR
      ID LIKE "*21*';
```

Then, if something matches "*21*", then it also matches "*2", so the last condition is redundant:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student_Enrollment
WHERE ID LIKE "*[258]*" OR
      ID LIKE "*1[174]*"
```

Comment: thank you, had to add a 1 inside the second brackets (to include 11), but now it works.